# Why is conda so much slower than pip when installing libraries?

Tags: performance, pip, conda

I've noticed a big difference in processing time between installing a library or package with `conda` versus `pip`. As an example, I created two new `conda` environments with Python 3.7. For each one, I activated it and download `geopandas`, and then deactivated it. In one `env`, I used `conda` to install the library; in the other, I used `pip`.

Here is how long it took each platform to install `geopandas` and all its dependencies:

CONDA 4.10.1

```
time conda install geopandas

real    1m52.037s
user    1m8.638s
sys 0m35.593s
```

PIP 21.1.2

```
time pip install geopandas

real    0m18.261s
user    0m13.455s
sys 0m2.868s
```

So in real time, `conda` was about six times slower than `pip`.
And this difference in speed is typical of my experience with these package managers.
Why such a difference to download the same library?

Comment: The Conda User Guide offers one possible reason for poor performance:
```Unlike many package managers, Anaconda’s repositories generally don’t filter or remove old packages from the index. This allows old environments to be easily recreated. However, it does mean that the index metadata is always growing, and thus conda becomes slower as the number of packages increases.```

Comment: One way to alleviate the issue mentioned above is to use specific versions, e.g. ```Instead of “numpy”, think “numpy=1.15” or even better, “numpy=1.15.4”```
More info here: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance

Answer (score 1):

Same experience for me. `conda` is unbelievably sluggish, sometimes even on newly created environments.

Conda is both a package manager and a virtual environment. So one option would be to create an empty conda environment and uses pip to install packages within it.

I've tried working with `pipenv` and `venv` but didn't really like the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is conda so much slower than pip when installing libraries?

As OP commented, The [Conda User Guide](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/conda-performance.html) offers one possible reason for poor performance:

> Unlike many package managers, Anaconda’s repositories generally don’t filter or remove old packages from the index. This allows old environments to be easily recreated. However, it does mean that the index metadata is always growing, and thus conda becomes slower as the number of packages increases.

---

> How to make conda faster?

As @PogLePog commented, one way of making conda faster is to specify package versions, as mentioned in https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance (emphasis mine):

> Be more specific. Letting conda filter more candidates makes it faster. **Instead of "numpy"**, think "numpy=1.15" or even better, **"numpy=1.15.4"**

Not exactly the best benchmark around, but I was installing tensorflow in docker and the performance improved drastically when I specified the version:

```
# Without specifying package version
 => [ 8/11] RUN conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow         887.0s 

# By specifying package version
 => [ 8/11] RUN conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.12.0  87.7s
```

Although this ~10x speedup is not always the case in my experience, specifying the version always provides faster or equal installation time.